# Menu not working correctly

Tags: java, input, menu, libgdx

Alright, i made my own little menu but have a small problem. when i use the 'w' and 's' keys only the play button, and highscore button gets selected. But when i use the arrow keys, they skip the highscores button and just alternate between Play and quit.

*I am using libgdx

```
public class levelSelection implements Screen {
           private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
           private Texture playB;
           private Texture exitB;
           private Texture hScoreB;
           private Texture backGround;
           MyGdxGame game;
           private int selectedButton;
           BitmapFont  font;

    public levelSelection(MyGdxGame game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor( 0f, 0f, 0f, 1f );
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 

        spriteBatch.begin();
        spriteBatch.draw(backGround, 0, 0);
        spriteBatch.draw(playB, 250, 450);
        spriteBatch.draw(exitB, 250, 350);
        spriteBatch.draw(hScoreB, 250, 400);
        spriteBatch.end();

        //Start Navigation Between menu buttons

            if( selectedButton == 2 && Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN) || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S)){
                selectedButton = 3;
                System.out.println("Quit button is selected");

            }
            if(selectedButton == 3 && Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP)|| Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.W)){
               selectedButton = 2;
               System.out.println("High Scores button is selected");

    }
            if(selectedButton == 2 && Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP)|| Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.W)){
                selectedButton = 1;
                System.out.println("Play button is selected");
            }
             if(selectedButton == 1 && Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN)|| Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S)){
                 selectedButton = 2;
                 System.out.println("High Scores button is selected");
             }

             //end navigation between menu buttons

                 if(selectedButton == 1 && Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.ENTER)){
                     game.setScreen(game.GameScreen);
                 }
                 if(selectedButton == 3 && Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.ENTER)){
                     game.dispose();
                 }

                 //Draw text according to selected button
                if(selectedButton == 2){
                    spriteBatch.begin();
                    font.draw(spriteBatch, "High Score Button is Selected!", 15, 15);
                    spriteBatch.end();
                }
                if(selectedButton == 3){
                    spriteBatch.begin();
                    font.draw(spriteBatch, "Quit Button is Selected!", 15, 15);
                    spriteBatch.end();
                }
                if(selectedButton == 1){
                    spriteBatch.begin();
                    font.draw(spriteBatch, "Play Button is Selected!", 15, 15);
                    spriteBatch.end();
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: I recommend to extend `InputAdapter` and override the keydown method. In this method you can switch the keycode and then do an `if(selected == 1) { //do something } else if (selected == 2) { //do something }...`. I think the error in your method is, that you don't use an if else but only if. So if it jumps in to the first if it can also jump in to the next one. I am not sure but try that.

Comment: You could also just increment/decrement selectedButton: `if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.Down)) { selectedButton++; selectedButton %= 3}` (now your Buttons are 0,1,2 instead of 1,2,3) and `if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP)) { selectedButon--; selectedButton = selectedButton < 0 ? 2 : selectedButton}`

Comment: For your next question just post the Code that is needed to solve the Problem. Not the whole Class. We dont need the packages or the loding of an asset if this doesnt cast the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
true || false = true
false || true = true
```

Lets combine this with a selectedButton == 3 ( lets say is false) And we have the first keydown not pressed but the second keydown. Then we do have this situation `false && false || true` -> `false || true = true`. And this should not happen. It's not selected but the key ifstatemen says `true` so it is not correct. (`System.out.println(false && false || true);`)

Here is the right solution to it. You always need to check both conidions and concatenate them with the or statement:

```
        if((selectedButton == 2 && Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN)) || (selectedButton == 2 && Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S))){
            selectedButton = 3;
            System.out.println("Quit button is selected");

        }
```

This would create the following boolean statemen `false || false && false ||true` -> `false && true` -> `false`.

Just to mention a more sweet solition you can also use the XOR instead of the 2 && concatinated with an ||.

```
    if(selectedButton == 2 && Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN) ^ Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S)){
        selectedButton = 3;
        System.out.println("Quit button is selected");

    }
```

Or brace the key or key.

*I am sorry if this isnt sematically fully correct. I am not concerned with the boolean order of java.*

Comment: you could also say `selectedButton == 2 && (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN) || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S))`

Comment: I have no idea what is happening in this answer but i will do my best to figure it out. Thanks for the help!